# React native production crash reports

Tags: react-native, crash, crash-reports, crashlytics

How do I get my hands on unexpected JS errors and their stack trace from React native app?

I was using Fabric before, but its reports are actually useless, as they aren't reflect what has happened in actual JS.

Comment: Have you found any free tool for crash reporting in React Native?

Comment: https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric

How about this? Will this work?